# Дано целое число N, которое больше нуля. Найти значения 1.1-1.2+1.3-N слагаемых (знаки чередуются). Условный оператор не использовать

Tags: c++, c

Пытаюсь решить простую задачку на С++, но не могу понять, как написать.

Прикладываю свой код ниже, но он неправильный.

Например, пользователь вводит `2`, а на выходе получает `-0.5`, так как 1.1 - 1.2 + 1.3 - 1.4 + 1.5 - 1.6 + 1.7 - 1.8 + 1.9 - 2 = -0.5.

UPD: желательно в цикле!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int N;
    double rez = 0;
    int A = 1;

    cout << "N=";
    cin >> N;

    for (double i = 1.1; i <= N; i += 0.1)
    {
        A = A * -1;
        rez += rez + A * (1.0 + i / 10);
    }
    cout << rez << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `rez += rez + A * (1.0 + i / 10);` — на самом деле `rez += A * (1.0 + i / 10);`

Comment: Спасибо, но ответ всё равно неверный - -1.15.

Comment: разбейте слагаемые на пары и посчитайте парой действий без цикла

Comment: А это первое, что в глаза бросилось. У вас и i неверное, и знак неверный, и...

Comment: @Harry мы все иногда спешим. По условию N - целое положительное.

Comment: @Harry Так число N является целым (без остатка), а 2.15 - вещественное.

Comment: Да, что-то я расслабился сегодня с утра...

Comment: Уточните условие - N слагаемых,  как в заголовке, или ряд заканчивается, когда очередной член по модулю достигает N?

Comment: Полагаю, что 2 - "когда очередной член по модулю достигает N".

Comment: Тогда `rez += rez + A * (1.0 + (i-1.0) / 10); A = -A;` изменение знака после сложения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы избавиться от проблем с вещественной арифметикой (сложив 0.1 и 1.2, вы не получите точно 1.3), можно шагать по целым числам:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int N;
    double rez = 0;
    int A = 1;

    cout << "N=";
    cin >> N;

    int M = (N - 1) * 10;  //число шагов
    for (int i = 1; i <= M; i++)
    {
        rez +=  (1.0 + i / 10.0)*A;
        A = - A;
   }
    cout << rez << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Более того, можно все сложения делать в целых, а в конце разделить на 10

```
  int intrez = 0;
  int M = (N - 1) * 10;  //число шагов
    for (int i = 1; i <= M; i++)
    {
        intrez +=  (10 + i)*A;
        A = - A;
   }
    cout << intrez/10.0 << endl;
```

Comment: Это интересное развитие событий

Comment: Вот это да! Большое, человеческое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {

    int N;

    cout << "N=";
    cin >> N;

    double rez = (N - 1) / -2.0;

    cout << rez << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Если нужно поциклить, тогда так:

```
int j = 1;
for (double i = 1.1; i <= N; i += 0.1, j = -j) rez += i * j;
```

Как раз вот тут и натыкаемся на проблему с вещественной арифметикой. Поэтому вариант с переходом к целым числам будет правильным.

```
int main() {
  int N, rez = 0, j = 1;
  cout << "N=";
  cin >> N;
  for (int i = 11; i <= N * 10; i += 1, j = -j) rez += i * j;
  cout << rez / 10.0 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это тоже подойдёт, но желательно решить в цикле for() или while()

Comment: Я такой фигнёй не занимаюсь :-)

Comment: Ахаха, понимаю вас)

Comment: Ну, вы в цикле просто по 0.5 вычитайте с каждым единичным отсчётом до N, и всё.